# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermock, spring-boot-test

After migrating an application to springboot, I'm facing these issues while running the jUnits. It's issue with the version conflicts. These are the dependencies and versions I'm using :

- mockito-core - 2.2.7
- mockito-all - 2.0.2-beta
- powermock-module-junit4 - 1.7.0RC2
- powermock-api-mockito - 1.7.0RC2
- powermock-classloading-objenesis - 1.7.0RC2

I can see that the MockingDetails class in **mockito-core** has this method getMockCreationSettings(), but **mockito-all** doesn't have. The test is somehow picking that class from the wrong dependency. Removing **mockito-all** will cause so many other tests to fail. Can someone help me with the fix ?

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:69)
at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:56)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:291)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: Im facing the same issue...Any joy?

Comment: Find out the Mockito Class(Cntl+Shft+T) that has this missing method and exclude the other dependencies in POM.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After facing the same issue, I looked at the stack trace:

```
Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockingDetails.getMockCreationSettings()Lorg/mockito/mock/MockCreationSettings;
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockReset.get(MockReset.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.resetMocks(ResetMocksTestExecutionListener.java:81)
    ...
```

I checked `MockReset.java` at line 107 and found that the `mockingDetails` is injected to the project from `mockito-all` with version of `1.9.5`.

Checking [here](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/MockingDetails.html#getMockCreationSettings())  I found the missing method is since version `2.1.0`

I run `mvn dependency:tree` to find which dependency is bringing with it this `mockito-all` and once found it, I excluded it from the pom:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>bla</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```